# How to Make Popup window as Global in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, mxml

Actually in my Flex Application have Some Popup windows and i want take some values in this Popup Window But The Values are Comming `NULL`

So how to Make a PopUp Window as Global? Because we are Using the values Globally.

Please Give Suggestion...

```
Edit
```

I'm Edit with some code...

```
Main.mxml(Main Aplication),    Demo1.mxml(PopUpWindow),    Demo2.mxml(PopUpWindow)
```

Now in Demo1.mxml have variable like...

```
[Bindable]private var arrayC:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();//Hear Some value their.
```

NOw i want Use arrayC in Demo2.mxml then ..

```
public var variable1:Demo1=new Demo1();
var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
ac = variable1.arrayC;
```

But hear ac contain Null Value Why?

Then,Now i'm Thinking Demo2.mxml(PopUpWindow) is Converting To Global Scope so it's value Used in Any Where .

Comment: What does `Make a PopUp Window as Global` mean? I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you perhaps trying to access values in the popup from elsewhere in the app?

Comment: I'm Update my Question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null because of you are tried create new instance so that each instance having their own state.

Also i bet you can't access arrayC ArrayCollection variable declared as private so you can't acccess.

Need to follow few steps

`[Bindable]public var arrayC:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();` //Make public variable

Use Singleton Class for you application

```
package com.foo.bar {

public class Model {

    private static var instance : Model;

    public function Model( enforcer : SingletonEnforcer ) {}

    public static function getInstance() : Model {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new Model( new SingletonEnforcer() );
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public var arrayC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
}
}

class SingletonEnforcer{}
```

For more details [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

```
private var popup:Demo1;
popup = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,Demo1,true) as Demo1;    
popup.arrayC =  Model.getInstance().arrayC; // Here set value from Model class
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);
```

Suppose you tried to access demo1.mxml arrayC variable in Demo2.mxml

```
var demo1_arrayC = Model.getInstance().arrayC;
```

Note that you can access arrayC arraycollection anywhere in your application like Demo2.mxml,Demo3...etc.

But better we have to avoid Singleton Class (unit test diffcult ..etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the values Globally, then no matter what you mean by the "Make a PopUp Window as Global", I strongly suspect that you would be best served by a singleton event dispatcher.

```
package com.example.demo.models {
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    [Bindable]
    class MyGlobalStuff extends EventDispatcher {
        public var someGlobalValue:*;

        private var _instance:MyGlobalStuff;

        public function MyGlobalStuff (lock:SingletonLock, target:IEventDispatcher=null) {
            super(target);
            if(!(lock is SingletonLock)) {
                throw(new Error("MyGlobalStuff is a singleton, please do not make foreign instances of it"));
            }
        }

        public static function getInstance():MyGlobalStuff {
             if(!_instance) {
                  _instance = new MyGlobalStuff (new SingletonLock());
             }
             return _instance;
        }
    }
}
class SingletonLock{}
```

The idea is this: that you would bind in your popup to

```
{myStuffModel.someGlobalValue}
```

myStuffModel would be initialized in your mxml as:

```
protected var myStuffModel:MyStuffModel = MyStuffModel.getInstance();
```

then in any other class throughout your application you can bind to or access the EXACT same data via the singleton model.